# Print data from database ( white page )

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with the print of data from DB.
I have a database called "Project" and a table: "Prenotazione".

I want print the elements from this table. so i use this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prenotazioni Richieste</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table> 
        <?php 
            $host="localhost"; 
            $uname="root"; 
            $psw="123456789"; 
            $nomedb="Project"; 
            mysql_connect($host,$uname,$psw);
            mysql_select_db($nomedb);
            $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Prenotazione");
            $r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

            echo $r[nome];

        ?> 

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

But i have only a white page without any elements. How can i solve? And why this code doesn't show nothing? Thank you.

Comment: usually, a blank page means that you have an error which is not displayed. have a look at your logs and/or enable display errors into your php config. for example, you have a syntax error on the last php line : the quotes are missing around `nome` : `echo $r['nome'];`

Comment: *"Warning: This extension [mysql] was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. "* http://php.net/en/mysql_connect

Comment: echo $r['nome'];turn on your error logging and you will see some errors

Comment: in my error log there isn't nothing :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ i don't think so

Comment: Try to var_dump($r); but please don't use Mysql function, read this [http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: I do think so. Please learn how to solve (syntax) errors on your own. [Turn errors on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display/41641608) and look at the errors that will appear.

Comment: @Kepz23 did you try to correct your echo as suggested by FatFreddy and me ?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I use var_dump($r) but nothing appears

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ Yes! It's strange, because it is not such a complicated code

Comment: @hellow I used also a connection.php that i use to put data into database and it works

Comment: What error do you get? Try to turn errors on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in line:

```
echo $r[nome];
```

To access data of specific column, you should use single quotes, otherwise it will be defined as a constant.

It should be like this:

```
echo $r['nome'];
```

I also advice you to use `mysqli` as `mysql` is deprecated, here is a simple example for what you want to achieve using mysqli.

`mysqli_connect` function receiving 4 arguments:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456789","Project");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Prenotazione";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Here you can fetch `$result` into an associative array.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Then you can access specific column in the database like this:

```
echo $row['nome'];
```

Comment: There is no syntax error, otherwise, please state it.

Comment: Thank you, my dear.

Comment: @hellow accessing tables name without single quotes, it will be defined as constant

Comment: @Kepz23 glad to help :))

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ You don't need to put the table name into single quotes, only if it contains some special characters, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @hellow I agree :)) i mean when he tried to echo $r[nome]; in this case nome is considered as constant, that's why it should be echo $row['nome'];

Comment: Alright, can you update your answer and state that exact issue as well as the suggestion to use mysqli as you already did?

Comment: @hellow edited :)) sorry in my reply i meant accessing columns without single quotes, not tables.